# How to pass input file name to xmlhttp.open as variable

Tags: javascript, html, file, variables, input

I want to pass name of selected file. It works if i put "filename" instead url. Here is my test code. Please help me to get this working.

```
<input id="upload" type="file" />

<script>
document.getElementById('upload').onchange = uploadOnChange;

function uploadOnChange() {
var filename = this.value;
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}

var url='"'+filename+'"'; 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var tag=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tag"); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: You want to pass filename to the server; and 'filename' gets passed, right?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is async, there's no `onreadystate` callback here, maybe you should look at some examples for ajax requests ?

Comment: Yes 'filename' gets passed, but if i use input function it doesnt work.